# Como usar o setState no if else

Tags: javascript, react

Preciso de ajuda para usar o .setState() no if else após o render(), isso se possível...

```
render() {
    const propsDesign = this.props.design, 
          propsIcon = this.props.icon,
          propsText = this.props.text,
          propsDescription = this.props.description;


    var object = {
        design: propsDesign,
        icon: propsIcon,
        text: propsText,
        description: propsDescription
    };

    if(propsDesign === 'normal' || propsDesign === 'narrator' || propsDesign === 'error' ) {
        console.log("Design true");
        this.setState({design: propsDesign});
    } else {
        console.log("Design false");
        this.setState({design: 'error'});
    }

    return <Container design=??? />;
}
```

Comment: Aqui é o Stackoverflow em Português, traduza sua pergunta por favor.

Comment: Nem percebi  que estava no em português, mas está traduzido

Comment: Sem problemas, só pra manter a ordem ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Não** use o setState dentro do render(), isso pode ocasionar loops infinitos, porque o metódo `render` é chamado quando o `state` é atualizado, então ao colocar o `setState` dentro do `render`, ele irá atualizar o `state` e chamar o `render`, atualizar o `state` novamente e chamar o `render` e por aí vai, o metódo `render` deve ser puro.

Se você precisa alterar o `state` use funções antes do `render()` e lifecycles do React.

E sim é possível usar o `if` com o `setState`, do jeito que você fez. Se você quer inicializar essas váriaveis assim que a página for montada, use o `componentDidMount()`. Exemplo:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const propsDesign = this.props.design, 
          propsIcon = this.props.icon,
          propsText = this.props.text,
          propsDescription = this.props.description;


    var object = {
        design: propsDesign,
        icon: propsIcon,
        text: propsText,
        description: propsDescription
    };

    if(propsDesign === 'normal' || propsDesign === 'narrator' || propsDesign === 'error' ) {
        console.log("Design true");
        this.setState({design: propsDesign});
    } else {
        console.log("Design false");
        this.setState({design: 'error'});
    }
}

render() {
    return <Container design={this.state.design} />;
}
```

Ref docs React Lifecycles: https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Ref sobre `setState()` no `render()`: https://blog.logrocket.com/an-imperative-guide-to-setstate-in-react-b837ceaf8304/

Comment: Obrigado! Resolveu meu problema e me fez entender um pouco mais sobre o state.